# Why TStream has Read, ReadBuffer, ReadData, ReadBufferData to read data? What is the difference between them?

Tags: delphi, stream

I see that TStream has many read functions, including Read, ReadBuffer, ReadData, ReadBufferData. They are similar to each other. I cannot understand why it offers so many variant of read function? In other libraries, there are normally only one or two Read functions.

I compare them carefully. The only difference I can find is:

1. Read is the basic read function and will return the number of bytes read.
2. ReadBuffer invoke Read and will raise exception if not read expected data.
3. ReadData can read data of a specific data, and will return the number of bytes read.
4. ReadDataBuffer invoke ReadData and will raise exception if not read expected data.

Is that correct?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: It is unclear what you don't understand... documentation is pretty clear in what each of those methods does. Why there are so many... because each behaves differently... pick the one that does what you need...

Comment: Documentation also suggest using specialized stream objects like TFileStream, TMemoryStream, TStringStream and others instead of using basic TStream class. The main reason why TStream has all of these methods is to ensure easy way for transferring data from one specialized stream to another since all are descendants from TStream.

Comment: For a LONG time, there was only `Read(Buffer)` available for reading raw bytes. More recently, `Read(Buffer)Data` overloads were added to make it easier to read many different kinds of data (boolean, chars, integers, floats, etc) than just raw bytes. That is the difference.